# trouble drawing custom views inside linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm working on a composite android component in an attempt to learn more about them. The structure is fairly simple, it contains a textview as a title, an editText view and a LinearLayout acting as a list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ListPoint"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Most of this works fine, as everything shows up on screen. I can add any type of ordinary view to the internal LinearLayout and it works perfectly. The problem is, I have a custom list element component that does not display properly. Its sole purpose is to display text, a simple way for me to override the onMeasure and the onDraw methods.

I can add these custom view elements just fine to the internal layout, and they will call the overriden onMeasure and onDraw methods. However, only the first element added to the LinearLayout will show up on screen. I've searched around but i can't find the reason why this happens. Below is the relevant code.

```
public CustomView(Context context, int oriX, int oriY, Paint textColor, LayoutParams params) {
        super(context);
        this.params = params;
        this.textColor= textColor;
        this.context = context;
        this.params = params;
        elementText = "";
        originX = oriX;
        originY = oriY;
    }

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("UsedMeasurements: " + getMeasuredWidth() + ", " + getMeasuredHeight());
        canvas.drawText(elementText, originX, originY, textColor);
        System.out.println(elementText + " drawn with origin: (" + originX + ", " + originY + ").");
    }

@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int preferredWidth = params.width;
        int preferredHeight = params.height;

        int usedWidth;
        int usedHeight;

        if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            usedWidth = widthSpec;
        else if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            usedWidth = Math.min(preferredWidth, widthSpec);
        else
            usedWidth = preferredWidth;

        if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            usedHeight = heightSpec;
        else if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            usedHeight = Math.min(preferredHeight, heightSpec);
        else
            usedHeight = preferredHeight;

        setMeasuredDimension(usedWidth, usedHeight);
    }
```

The print actions inside the onDraw function are there just to make sure that they get called. And they do, so that is not the problem. I have also made sure that the origin coordinates for the drawText function are inside the actual screenspace. I would really appreciate some assistance with this.